# Google Video API

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I am building a training tool for a client. They require a secure streaming server. I want to use Google Video (as part of Google Apps for Business) but I cannot find any information about the API. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, unfortunately, there is no API fo Google Video for Business at the moment:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=0be88ad2ae25cae3&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I'd second that. I wanted to use Google Video for the same thing but found out there was no API.

I used flash video files (*.flv), apache mod_h264 and a flash player from http://flv-player.net/players/mini/